# Can't access object properties in jQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call this code:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.email);
```

I get this result:

```
{"userName":"2","email":"2","firstName":"2","lastName":"2","isAdmin":"0","isEnabled":"1"} index.php:162
undefined
```

The first `console.log(data);` outputs correctly.  Then, I want to access the `email` property of the `data` object, and to do so I use `console.log(data.email);`.  However, as you can see above, it says that it's, "undefined."

Why can't I access this property (or any properties)?  Note:  I have also tried `data['email']` which didn't work, either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't realize that jQuery doesn't auto-parse the returned JSON to an object.  It was just a JSON string.  To fix, I just had to do this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Cross-browser:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Comment: You can also fix it by telling jquery your server is returning JSON. `dataType: "json"` or setting the server's response content-type to `"application/json"`

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was `contentType` so it wasn't working!  I like your solution better.

Comment: You should use `$.parseJSON` instead of `JSON.parse()` because jquery handles it in a cross-browser way.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I could show the object by console.log, but I couldn't access any attribute for a simple thing: I wasn't realizing that my JSON was wrongly structured, as an array with one single object. Then I could access its attribute using a index.

`console.log(data.email);`

`undefined`

but then I tried...

`console.log(data[0].email);`

`finallyhereismyattribute@json.com`

I just fixed my model and it works perfectly. Thanks to my coleague Aaron Lil!

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue. And to have it fixed, I needed to create new array and then put each values of the data object in that array by iterating "data" like the following:

```
var arrayTest = [];

$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    arrayTest["email"] = value.email;
    arrayTest["andsoforth"] = value.andsoforth;
    //etc...
});

// Now retrieve data by using arrayTest
console.log(arrayTest["email"]);
```